# Column edit on undefined field with ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have configured the ag-grid for the column definitions like this below

```
    {
        headerName: 'Model Level',
        field: 'ModelLevelTimeSeries.Id.Value',
        editable: false,
        cellRendererFramework: RenderEntityComponent,
        cellStyle: { textAlign: "center" },
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
    }
```

Basically the field from the back-end can return null

```
"ModelLevelTimeSeries": {
        "Id": null
    }
```

or

```
"ModelLevelTimeSeries": {
    "Id": {
        "Value": "dec70622-3ab3-4b47-a324-f69a14a53beb"
    }
}
```

When I edit the cell value, it returns `null` for the `params.value` in `agInit` method.
I'm using "ag-grid": "^17.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^17.0.0".

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use value setter for your coldefs

```
{
  headerName: 'Model Level',
  field: 'ModelLevelTimeSeries.Id.Value',
  editable: false,
  cellRendererFramework: RenderEntityComponent,
  cellStyle: { textAlign: "center" },
  suppressSizeToFit: true,

  valueSetter: function(params: any){
     if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
         params.data[params.colDef.field] = (params.newValue) !== "" ? params.newValue.toUpperCase() : "";
         return true;
     } 
     else {
         return false;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add , cellRnderer function in your column defincation

```
cellRenderer: params => params.value ? params.value : ''
```

it will be like this now

```
   {
        headerName: 'Model Level',
        field: 'ModelLevelTimeSeries.Id.Value',
        editable: false,
        //add below line
        cellRenderer: params => params.value ? params.value : ''
        cellRendererFramework: RenderEntityComponent,
        cellStyle: { textAlign: "center" },
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, using params.data[params.colDef.field] in the valueSetter will not work if the field is.a.nested.key, because params.colDef.field just returns a string like "ModelLevelTimeSeries.Id.Value"

I have, for now, relied on lodash's set() to do it inside a valueSetter:

```
import * as set from 'lodash/set'

changeDetectValueSetter (params) {
  if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
    set(params.data, params.colDef.field, params.newValue) // had to use lodash set, because params.colDef.field is a string representation of a nested object key
    // params.data.instruction.billingrecord.invoice_number = params.newValue // could have done this, but it's fixed for that field.
    // params.data[params.colDef.field] = params.newValue // this does not work at all if the field is.a.nested.key
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
},
```